# $super probe in Classy javascript framework

Tags: javascript

I can not understand the following lines in [Classy](http://classy.pocoo.org) framework:

```
/* we check if $super is in use by a class if we can.  But first we have to
 check if the JavaScript interpreter supports that.  This also matches
 to false positives later, but that does not do any harm besides slightly
 slowing calls down. */
  var probe_super = (function(){$super();}).toString().indexOf('$super') > 0;
  function usesSuper(obj) {
    return !probe_super || /\B\$super\b/.test(obj.toString());
  }
```

when and how to make the probe_super return false?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment said, it is to check if the JavaScript interpreter supports that, so you could do nothing with it, it depends on the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: So... which interpreter doesn't support, NodeJS?

Comment: @jiyee ...Do you know some interpreter support?

Comment: @jiyee It's just a prevent I think, no javascript interpreter supports that now.

Comment: Ok, I know what that means and what did you mean. sorry for such stupid question.